# Semantic in limits calculation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The best way to explain this question is by example.
Calculate: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-3)^{n+1}-4^n+5}{3^{n+2}+2^n-5}$.
So, 
$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-3)^{n+1}-4^n+5}{3^{n+2}+2^n-5}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(-3)^{n+1}}{4^n}-\frac{4^n+5}{4^n}}{\frac{3^{n+2}}{4^n}+\frac{2^n-5}{4^n}}="\frac{0-1+0}{0+0-0}"="-\frac{1}{0}"=-\infty.
\end{aligned}
$
But,
$
\begin{aligned}\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-3)^{n+1}-4^n+5}{3^{n+2}+2^n-5}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(-3)^{n+1}}{-4^n}-\frac{4^n+5}{-4^n}}{\frac{3^{n+2}}{-4^n}+\frac{2^n-5}{-4^n}}="\frac{0+1+0}{-0-0+0}"="\frac{1}{0}"=\infty.
\end{aligned}
$

The sign of the zeros in the denominator is unimportant because $-0=0=+0$. So i'm wondering what is the explanation of this. Thank you.

Comment: $-\infty$ is the right result.

Comment: Of course. But the question is what is wrong with my interpretation.

Comment: Don't write $\lim_n u_n=\ldots$ if you haven't proved that the limit of $u_n$ exists in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best answer is: while $\frac01$ and $\frac{-0}1$ are the same, $\frac10$ and $\frac1{-0}$ are not the same—for reasons that have to do with why "$=$" is not the same as $=$.

Consider the simpler example $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{-n}{1}$.
The two expressions analogous to your calculations are
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{-n}{1} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{-n}n}{\frac1n} &"=" \frac{-1}0 "=" -\infty \\
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{-n}{1} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{-n}{-n}}{\frac1{-n}} &"=" \frac{1}{-0} "=" -\infty \\
\text{but not} \qquad \cdots &"=" \frac{1}{-0} "=" \frac{1}{0} "=" \infty.
\end{align*}
If you like, take this as additional reason to believe that $\infty$ is not a number and that dividing by $0$ really isn't allowed.

The quotes around the "$=$" symbols are emphasizing that we are using these symbols (and $\frac10$, etc.) as a shorthand for careful reasoning about infinite limits—but the reasoning is what's rigorous, not some pattern we might be tempted to deduce from the shorthand symbols themselves.

In your example, can you verify that the numerator of the original expression is negative when $n$ is large, while the denominator is positive when $n$ is large? Does that help you evaluate the limit of their ratio?

Comment: How would you see that $"\frac{0+1+0}{-0-0+0}"="\frac{1}{-0}"$ and not $"\frac{0+1+0}{-0-0+0}"="\frac{1}{0}"$ and how would you avoid/interpret such situation?

Comment: In other words, is it all about tricks? should I manipulate the expression anyhow when encountered these problematic expressions?

Comment: Quite the opposite: using "$=$" $\frac10$ is a trick (often a useful one), while understanding how limits works—in particular, the exact meaning of a limit tending to $-\infty$ rather than $\infty$—is what you want to cultivate.

Comment: I know how limits work. I know the definitions of limits and how to prove it by definition. I don't really understand why and how tricks work. that's the story. This is why I ask about this trick, for example.

Comment: If I solve with tricks, I have to master those.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, consider the value of your denominator as it approaches zero.

Personally, I would prefer dividing by a factor that gives you a constant in your denominator (which would you pick?). The answer should be the same.

Comment: "consider the value of your denominator as it approaches zero". Well, even then I can't know if it's converge from the negative or positive side. And yes I would prefer to see a constant in the denominator but I would like to understand properly all kind of expressions as well.

Comment: It doesn’t seem too hard to prove that the denominator in the second example is negative. Intuitively, you can see that the 5 term, which is not exponentiated, will converge to zero a lot faster than the other terms in the denominator.